# How do I match something like this using perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

The file looks like

```
[N the computer end] [M whatever] [N you look] [N why not]
```

I only need the words in the bracket that start with `[N`
so  here I want to get  the computer end you look why not
they may or may not in the same line

I tried something like this:

```
if($line =~/\[N(.+?)\]/)
```

but it only match the first one of each line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `g` modifier on the regular expression to look for "g"lobal matches.  Either like this:

```
while ($line =~ /\[N(.+?)\]/g) {
    # $1 contains the text between "[N" and "]"
}
```

Or like this:

```
my @matches = $line =~ /\[N(.+?)\]/g;
# @matches contains all of the matching items of text
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change it to a while loop to iterate over each group match.  The [Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Global-Matching) illustrates this.